# How to remove schema name from dbvisualizer export from command line

Tags: dbvisualizer

When I export a result set using @export,
It gives me 'INSERT INTO abc.employee .......'
I need to remove the schema name from here.....

How can I get statement like 'INSERT INTO employee ......'?

I am using following method

**export.sql :**

@export on;

@export set filename="C:\exports\${dbvis-object}$_new.sql" format="sql" BinaryFormat="Base64";

select * from abc.employee;

@export off;

**export.bat :**

call dbviscmd.bat -connection "xyz" -sql "@run export.sql; "

Comment: There is a parameter for @export set, ie 'SqlQualifyTableName'(true/false)
http://confluence.dbvis.com/display/UG91/Exporting+Query+Results
But when I am using this parameter....it gives me an error saying - 'parameter SqlQualifyTableName is not valid for this command'

Answer (score 3):

**SqlQualifyTableName** was renamed to **SqlQualifyObjectName** in DbVisualizer 9.2.